# Can't clear process running on port 8080

Tags: port, pkill, spring-cloud-zookeeper

I am trying to clear port 8080, I tried

```
lsof -i :8080    
kill pid
```

but it keep on getting created on new port

```
 ps -aef | grep 2841                              
 /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/bin/java -Dzookeeper.log.dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zookeeper/3.8.1_1/libexec/bin/../logs -Dzookeeper.log.file ............
```

Can someone please help how to stop this process from keep on getting created? I tried re-start too but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have [Zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/index.html) installed as a service.

You can stop the service issuing this command:

```
sudo bin/zkServer.sh stop
```

Or you can uninstall Zookeeper...

Take a look at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/715404/how-can-i-stop-zookeeper-on-ubuntu)